# Getting values of a custom taxonomy dropdown

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy dropdown (`custom_authors`) which is displayed in the comments form when logged in to select a different author than the logged in one.

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'taxonomy_dropdown' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'taxonomy_dropdown' );
function taxonomy_dropdown() {
    wp_dropdown_categories( array(
        'name'       => 'alt_comment_user',
        'taxonomy'   => 'custom_authors',
        'hide_empty' => false
     ));   
}
```

The following function should save the selected value (`name` and `id`) but I don’t manage to get it to work.

```
add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'save_user_settings' );
function save_user_settings($input) {

    if(current_user_can('moderate_comments') && isset($_POST['alt_comment_user'])){    

        $user = get_user_by('id', (int)$_POST['alt_comment_user']);

        $my_fields = array(
            'comment_author'       => $user->name,
            'user_ID'              => $user->ID,
        );

        // escape for db input
        foreach($my_fields as &$field)
            $field = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->escape($field);
            $input = $my_fields + $input;   
    }  
    return $input;
}
```

The output I get the name "Anonymous" as comment author.

Can somebody help how I get the correct value from the taxonomy dropdown? I think I have to change especially this line `get_user_by('id', (int)$_POST['alt_comment_user']);` to [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) but I don’t know how …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_user_by()` receives user data not taxonomy terms. Since you are not dealing with real userdata you'll have to use `get_term_by()` to receive the term name. You would use it like this:

`$username = get_term_by( 'id', (int) $_POST['alt_comment_user'], 'custom_authors' );`

Fixed code:

```
function taxonomy_dropdown() {
    wp_dropdown_categories( array(
        'name'       => 'alt_comment_user',
        'taxonomy'   => 'custom_authors',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ));   
}
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'taxonomy_dropdown' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'taxonomy_dropdown' );

function save_user_settings( $input ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( current_user_can( 'moderate_comments' ) && isset( $_POST['alt_comment_user'] ) ) {
        $username = get_term_by( 'id', (int) $_POST['alt_comment_user'], 'custom_authors' );
        $my_fields = array(
            'comment_author' => $wpdb->escape( $username->name ),
            'user_ID'        => 0,
        );

        $input = $my_fields + $input;   
    }
    return $input;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'save_user_settings' );
```